# Poppulating Extjs grid from a json file

Tags: java, javascript, json, extjs

I am new to extjs and am struck up here. I just edited the code given in net but I am not getting the values updated in my grid dynamically

My code is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<script>
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.define('User', {
            extend : 'Ext.data.JsonStore',
            fields : [ {
                name : 'Date',
                type : 'string'
            }, {
                name : 'TimeStamp',
                type : 'string'
            }, {
                name : 'type',
                type : 'string'
            }, {
                name : 'Class Name',
                type : 'string'
            }, {
                name : 'Method',
                type : 'string'
            }, {
                name : 'Message',
                type : 'string'
            } ]
        });

        var user = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId : 'user',
            model : 'User',
            autoLoad : 'true',
            proxy : {
                url : 'C:\Users\753734\Desktop\New folder\LogHandlers\WebContent\Json12.json',
                reader : {
                    type : 'json'
                }
            }
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store : user,
            id : 'user',
            title : 'Users',
            columns : [ {
                header : 'DATE',
                dataIndex : 'Date'
            }, {
                header : 'TIMESTAMP',
                dataIndex : 'TimeStamp'
            }, {
                header : 'CLASSNAME',
                dataIndex : 'Class Name'
            }, {
                header : 'METHOD',
                dataIndex : 'Method'
            }, {
                header : 'MESSAGE',
                dataIndex : 'Message'
            } ],
            height : 3000,
            width : 3000,
            renderTo : Ext.getBody()
        });
        store.load();
    });
</script>
```

The error is

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)
Timestamp: Mon, 23 Dec 2013 11:22:30 UTC


Message: Object expected
Line: 19450
Char: 9
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all-debug.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 9886
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all-debug.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js


Message: 'events' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 114045
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Users/753734/Desktop/New%20folder/LogHandlers/WebContent/extjs/ext-all.js
```

Comment: Why is this tagged java?

Comment: you didn't define model!

Comment: how to define model!?

Answer (score 1):

```
Ext.define('User', {
   extend: 'Ext.data.Model,
   fields: [
       {name: 'Date', type: 'string'},
       ...
   ]
})

var userStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    model: 'User',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'C:\Users\753734\Desktop\New folder\LogHandlers\WebContent\Json12.json',
        reader: {
           type: 'json',
           root: 'userList', // this is json array name
           idProperty: 'USER_ID' // you should provide one unique column in JSON, you can hide this column in grid with hidden: true property
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the sample JSON Object. Take notice that `ctgMains` which is `root` property above!
Also make sure one unique colum must be available in the json object, othwerwise you can't see data in the grid is because of the data conflict!

```
{"ctgMains":[{"CUST_ASSORT_SECTION_ID":"1","CTG_SECTION":"HORECA"},{"CUST_ASSORT_SECTION_ID":"7","CTG_SECTION":"SCO"},{"CUST_ASSORT_SECTION_ID":"3","CTG_SECTION":"TRADER"}]}
```

Comment: impossible, check your json data!

Comment: yes, the code sample above working in 4.2 edition! Or put everything in jsfiddle and share with me!

Answer (score 0):

try to define a model:

```
Ext.define('ModelNameHere', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'date', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'timestamp', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'type', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

Then add property to store:

```
model: 'ModelNameHere'
```